# Replacing Multiple Chars to Multiple values in a String in C#

Tags: c#, string, replace, char

The issue here is that , application only takes the last Replace method (Z to G)

is there any way possible to make it Get all of them ? ((n to o) for example)

(here is the image)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyK4M.png

Comment: You need to either use a more functional replace algorithm (e.g. regular expression replace) or chain the calls to replace. The problem with chaining the calls may be that you overwrite previous replaces if you don't chain in an order that prevents this - for instance - `textVar.Replace('A', 'z').Replace('z', 'C')` would result in all your `z` characters being replaced by `C` in the final output

Comment: You should post your code in your question, not in a linked image. The reason it's not working the way you expect is that you do all the replacements using `txt1` (which never changes), and only keep the result of the last one in `txt2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> application only takes the last Replace method (Z to G)

This is because `string`s are immutable. More importantly, your algorithm is broken, because subsequent substitutions "see" the results of the previous ones. You cannot do the replacements sequentially - if you want to get correct results, you must consider them all at once. Otherwise, `l` will become `o`, even though your algorithm replaces `l` with `n`:

```
// Let's say the text is "Hello"
text = text.replace('l', 'n'); // The text becomes "Henno"
... // More substitutions
text = text.replace('n', 'o'); // The text becomes "Heooo"
```

Here is how you can fix it:

```
StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
foreach (char c in txt1.Text) {
    char toAppend;
    switch (c) {
        case 'I': toAppend = 'L'; break;
        case 'j': toAppend = 'n'; break;
        case 'J': toAppend = 'N'; break;
        case 'k': toAppend = 'l'; break;
        ...
        default: toAppend = '?';
    }
    res.append(toAppend);
}
```

Comment: This is the most helpful answer.

Answer (score 3):

You're modifying the same source over and over again, instead of modifying the result from the previous call.

Try

```
string replaced =  txt1.Text.Replace(...);
replaced = replaced.Replace(...);
replaced = replaced.Replace(...);
...

txt2.Text = replaced;
```

Or better yet, use [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) to repeatedly mutate a string without littering the heap with intermediate strings.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(txt1.Text);

sb.Replace(...);
sb.Replace(...);
sb.Replace(...);

txt2.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: This is broken, because subsequent substitutions see the results of previous ones.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Then that's a problem in the OPs alright, right? The code I've shown does what the OP wants it to do.

Comment: Of course! I am pointing out that the problem is not only in the implementation of the algorithm, but in the algorithm itself.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Agreed. @Nirex, as I've already explained, that's because you're calling `Replace` on the same string over and over again. Each time you call `Replace`, the result from the previous call will be forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

You keep applying the replacement to your original value.  `Replace` returns a new String instead of modifying the one you pass in.